# Falsy values vs null, undefined, or empty string

Tags: javascript

I've worked with jQuery over the years. However, recently, I've found myself getting deeper into the JavaScript language. Recently, I've heard about "truthy" and falsey values. However, I don't fully understand them. Currently, I have some code that looks like this:

```
var fields = options.fields || ['id', 'query'];
```

I need to identify if fields is null, undefined, or has a length of 0. I know the long way is to do:

```
if ((fields === null) || (fields === undefined) || (fields.length === 0)) {
 ...                    
}
```

My question is, is the following the same:

```
if (!fields)  {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Well [looky here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310)

Answer (score 24):

In programming, truthiness or falsiness is that quality of those boolean expressions which don't resolve to an actual boolean value, but which nevertheless get interpreted as a boolean result.

In the case of C, any expression that evaluates to zero is interpreted to be false.  In Javascript, the expression `value` in

```
if(value) {
}
```

will evaluate to true if `value` is not:

```
null
undefined
NaN
empty string ("")
0
false
```

**See Also**
[Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Answer (score 9):

The set of "truthy" and "falsey" values in JavaScript comes from the [`ToBoolean` abstract operation defined in the ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2), which is used when coercing a value to a boolean:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Argument Type | Result                                                   |
|---------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Undefined     | false                                                    |
|---------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Null          | false                                                    |
|---------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Boolean       | The result equals the input argument (no conversion).    |
|---------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Number        | The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN;   |
|               | otherwise the result is true.                            |
|---------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| String        | The result is false if the argument is the empty String  |
|               | (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.      |
|---------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Object        | true                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From this table, we can see that `null` and `undefined` are both coerced to `false` in a boolean context. However, your `fields.length === 0` does not map generally onto a false value. If `fields.length` is a string, then it will be treated as `false` (because a zero-length string is `false`), but if it is an object (including an array) it will coerce to `true`.

If `fields` should be a string, then `!fields` is a sufficient predicate. If `fields` is an array, your best check might be:

```
if (!fields || fields.length === 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**

**No**, they are not the same.

But this:

`if (!fields)  {
 ...
}`

Is the same as this:

`if ((fields === null) || (fields === undefined) || (fields === 0) || (fields === '') || (fields === NaN) || (fields === flase)) {
 ...

}`

**Long (and better) Answer:**

Let's first talk about truthy and falsy values.

It's all about what happens when you evaluate something as a boolean. In JavaScript, this happens when you use things like `if` statements; logical operators like `||`, `!`, or `&&`; or the `Boolean()` function.

The `Boolean()` function accepts a value and returns either `true` or `false`.

For Example:

`var age = 1; // Let's evaluate age as a boolean
Boolean(age); // true`

*Go ahead and try this in a node repl.*

A boolean can only be `true` or `false`, so the return value of `Boolean()` **must** be either `true` or `false`. In this case, we passed in the value `1`, and when evaluated as a boolean, `1` is `true`.

**Important: When evaluated as a boolean, a value must be either true or false.** Those are the only two options.

In JavaScript, there are only **6** falsy values. Values that will be `false` when evaluated as a boolean. They are: `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`. So if any of these values are evaluated as a boolean, they will be false:

`Boolean(false) // false
Boolean(0) // false
Boolean("") // false
Boolean(null) // false
Boolean(undefined) // false
Boolean(NaN) // false`

This means that any other value, in JavaScript, will be `true` when evaluated as a boolean. So every other value in JavaScript is truthy.

Another easy way to evaluate something as a `boolean` is by using the `!` operator. Just like the `Boolean` function, this evaluates a value as a boolean. But truthy values become `false` and falsy values become `true`.

`!false // true
!0 // true
!"" / true
!null // true
!undefined // true
!NaN // true`

*Again, try this out in a node repl or something to make sure you understand.*

So this statement:

`if (!fields)  {
 ...
}`

Is saying the following: "if `fields`, when evaluated as a boolean, is false, then run the code inside this if statement."

As for your first statement:

`var fields = options.fields || ['id', 'query'];`

You are working with the logical OR operator, which is worth reading about to make sure that you understand. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 0):

Your code means:

```
var fields;
if (options.fields)
    fields = options.fields;
else
    fields = ['id', 'query'];
```

Now `options.fields` is converted to a boolean value. By definition `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""` is converted to `false`, (mostly) anything else is converted to `true` (but I don't want to be so precise).

It does not mean the same, because the `fields.length === 0` line. Empty arrays and other objects are converted to `true`.

*note: Javascript is sometimes a big mess... For example there is no real need for 2 type checking operators (typeof and instanceof). It just confuses ppl when `true instanceof Boolean` does not work and using `typeof(true) == "boolean"` is error prone because of typing a string without autocompletion. Maybe in some new versions these problems will be solved.*

Answer (score -1):

You can try (!! fields) if the fields element is null, undefined or has a length of 0 it would return true. Or (!!! fields) then this would return true.

the double ! or !! will force true or false.
I wish I can find a good definition for this but I don't seem to be able to find it again.

Comment: "!!!" is the same as "!" by definition, as is "!!!!!" and "!!!!!!!".
"Notting" a value can be used to confirm that something is truthy or falsy, which definitely has its place, but it doesn't fully answer the OP's question. That is, what exactly are truthy or falsy values?

Comment: I found an article that better describes the not not operator:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1784-using-double-not-operator-for-boolean-type-casting.htm

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

It will turn your condition into a boolean value.